# Using bitcoin-qt in bitcoin-core: How to tie my wallet to my email address?

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, address, client

I can send and receive money using listreceivedbyaddress.

[How do I get my public address in Bitcoin Core?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/42682/how-do-i-get-my-public-address-in-bitcoin-core#)

However, I would like to connect this address to my email address.

1. Is this possible?
2. If this is possible, how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Normally, the software doesn't support such things. The wallet doesn't store any personal information.

However, there are web exchanges like coinbase, that lets you to use email address when sending cryptocurrency. But, it was only for clients under the same exchange.

Comment: May be you can customize the software to accept such changes. But it requires good understanding of its code.