# How can I see my public wallet address in bitcoin core?

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, address

I've downloaded bitcoin core version 22.0. I created a wallet by this command:

```
[amirreza@localhost bin]$ ./bitcoin-wallet -wallet=test-wallet create
Topping up keypool...
Wallet info
===========
Name: test-wallet
Format: bdb
Descriptors: no
Encrypted: no
HD (hd seed available): yes
Keypool Size: 2000
Transactions: 0
Address Book: 0
```

But I don't know how to find my public address (which can be used to receive bitcoin from others). I also tried using `bitcoin-qt` to find my wallet address but I didn't find anything.

I've seen this [question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/42682/101040) but answers were not helpful to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is not singular "wallet address". A wallet is a collection of addresses, not a single address. You can get an address that your wallet will control by using the `getnewaddress` RPC, or by clicking "Create new receiving address" in the "Receive" tab of bitcoin-qt.

Comment: for every transaction I can use different address without any cost? if yes, there is no problem with anonymity in bitcoin. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, each receiving transaction can use another address. The anonymity problems start the moment you have to use 2 of your addresses as input for a sending transaction, which makes everyone aware of the fact that those 2 addresses are likely controlled by the same person.

Comment: If you're more interested in privacy aspects of using Bitcoin, you may find this wiki page interesting: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Privacy

Answer (score 2):

Modern Account-Wallets are "HD" type, generated from a seed (mnemonic + passphrase), BIP32/BIP39 plus BIP44 compliant usually.

For privacy, no address should ever be re-used, you generate a new one for each transaction, or rather your wallet-client software does.

Ideally your account-wallet secrets (seed, xprv & privkeys) for spending are protected by a hardware wallet, which signs transactions generated by your watch-only (pubkeys & addresses only) wallet-client software.

Answer (score 2):

People here are great but still the question was not answered. For instance, I created a new wallet (p2tr) and an address was also created, iirc. However, I only created this address for the experience of having a p2tr address. I never used it. Now, I woul like to try something with this address and I need to "get it out" of the wallet. I didn't save the address anywhere. So, the question remains. How do we get the address out of a wallet? I don't need nor want to create new addresses. I just need to get the one I created some time ago!
Thank you
Psy

Edited:
A possibility to get the addresses out is:

Get the wallets from your Bitcoin node with the follwoing command:

```
bitcoin-cli listwallets
```

Then, get the labels from the wallet you're interested in, in case you have more than one wallet in your node, with the following command:

```
bitcoin-cli --rpcwallet=<MyWalletName> listlabels
```

Finally get the addresses out from the labels of interest, if more than one:

```
bitcoin-cli --rpcwallet=<MyWalletName> getaddressesbylabel <MyLabelofInterest>
```

Comment: Hey, if you have another question, please start another topic. Please don't ask new questions in the answer section of an existing topic. If you want to know more about how our sites works, check out our [tour].

Comment: It was not another question. It was the same but slightly different scenario. And I end up answering it and probably the OP too!

Comment: I see. I'm sorry, I misread your intent.